# Why is my kick command only giving errors?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

Wassup people. I am working on some admin commands. At this moment it's going to be a kick command. But it's only giving errors. If you remove a line or change anything, it will infect the code in another place.

That's what I am struggling with.

Here's my code:

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require("discord.js");
const discord = require("discord.js");
const { MessageEmbed, Collection, Permissions } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: "kick",
    description: "Kicks a specific member",
    admin: true,
    usage: "[Target] [Reason] [Messages]",
    options: [
        {
            name: "Target",
            description: "Provide A User To Kick.",
            type: "USER",
            required: true,
        },
        {
            name: "Reason",
            description: "Provide A Reason For The Kick.",
            type: "STRING",
            required: true,
        },
    ],

    async execute(message, args, client) {
        const target = message.mentions.members.first();
        const reason = args.slice(1, args.length - 1).join(" ");

        console.log("Target: ");

        const embed = new MessageEmbed().setTitle("There seems to be a error to execute this command").setColor("RED").setDescription("Are you sure you got the right permission? And are you providing a reason?");

        if (!message.member.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.KICK_MEMBERS))
            return message.reply({ embeds: [embed] }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });

        if (target.id === message.member.id)
            return message.reply({
                embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setTitle("There seems to be a error to execute this command").setColor("RED").setDescription("Why would you kick yourself?")],
                ephemeral: true,
            });

        if (target.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.KICK_MEMBERS)) {
            return message.reply({
                embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setColor("RED").setDescription("You can't kick this person.")],
            });
        }

        const DMEmbed = new MessageEmbed().setTitle(`You've Been Kicked From ${message.guild.name}`).setColor("RED").setTimestamp().addFields(
            {
                name: "Reason:",
                value: reason,
            },
            {
                name: "Kicked By:",
                value: message.member.user.toString(),
            }
        );

        await target
            .send({
                embeds: [DMEmbed],
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    },
};
```

Comment: Try to remove the async at the execute line

Comment: That will only let the DMEmbed getting disabled

Comment: Can you please provide the error you are receiving?

Comment: Done! I am sorry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, it is most likely the `reason` field being empty.

You can change it to this to ensure there is a fallback!

```
            {
                name: "Reason:",
                value: reason.replace(/\s/g, '') == "" ? "Not Provided" : reason,
            },
```

Comment: Yes! That was it! Now I got this error :) https://sourceb.in/ajpkf67lGK

Comment: You can either remove the `await` or make sure `async` is added before execute, incase you removed it as someone said above.

Comment: at both points, Its already the case. The await is there, and the async is in the right place as well.

Comment: Try removing the await then, should be good.

Comment: Nice! No errors. Nice! Its sending the embed! Not nice! It isn't kicking anyone

Comment: Make sure you have `target.kick()`

Comment: I was dumb, but thanks for your help!